# Is there a way to check if folder exists in s3 using aws cli?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

Let's say I have a bucket named Test which has folder Alpha/TestingOne,Alpha/TestingTwo . I want to check if a folder named Alpha/TestingThree is present in my bucket using aws cli . I did try aws

`s3api head-object --bucket Test --key Alpha/TestingThree`

But seems the head-object is for files and not for folders . So is there a way to check if a folder exists in aws s3 using aws cli api .

Comment: _Why_ do you need to check if it exists?

Answer (score 14):

Using aws cli,

```
aws s3 ls s3://Test/Alpha/TestingThree
```

If It is exists, it shows like below, else returns nothting.

```
                           PRE TestingThree
```

Note that S3 is flat structure (acutually no hierarchy like directory). 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/using-folders.html

Comment: For `bash`, you can use `if [[ $(aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/myfolder | head) ]]; then echo "do stuff"; else echo "folder does not exist"; fi`

Comment: This will return false positives if you have folders with similar names;
for example the following will also be returned if it existed`s3://Test/Alpha/TestingThreeV2`

Comment: As noted by @JSchmidt this returns false positives. Instead you should append @ryankim example with "/" to get the directory content instead. eg:
`aws s3 ls s3://Test/Alpha/TestingThree/`. Note that this will return the contents of the directory rather than "PRE TestingThree"

Answer (score 6):

There seem to be **no** way to test if a '*folder*' exists in s3 bucket. That should be somehow related to the fact that everything is an 'object' with a key/value.

As an option, you could utilize list-objects-v2 or list-objects to check for the 'contents' of a prefix (aka '*folder*'):

```
$ aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket <bucket_name> --prefix <non_exist_prefix_name> --query 'Contents[]'
null
```

Prefix (aka '*folder*') that doesn't exist will always return 'null' for such query. Then you can use comparison against '**null**' value:

```
$ test "$result" == "null" && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'
```

Comment: I'm using this, and limiting the response with --max-items 0

Answer (score 3):

Folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3. For example you could use this command:

```
aws s3 cp foo.txt s3://my-bucket/folder1/folder2/foo.txt
```

This would work successfully even if `folder1` and `folder2` do not exist. This is because the filename (`Key`) of an Amazon S3 object contains the full path. Amazon S3 is a flat storage system that does not use folders. However, to make things easier for humans, the S3 management console makes it "appear" as though there are folders, and it is possible to list objects that have a `CommonPrefix` (which is like a path).

If a new folder is created in the S3 management console, it actually creates a zero-length object with the same name as the folder. This makes it possible to show "empty folders" even though they don't actually exist.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers provided so far come close but have flaws.

To accurately determine if the object exists and it is a directory you want to do the following

```bash
aws s3 ls s3://BUCKET_NAME/PATH/TO/DIRECTORY/ && echo "It exists!" || echo "It doesn't exist!"
```

This works as follows:

```bash
aws s3 ls s3://BUCKET_NAME/PATH/TO/DIRECTORY/
```

Will return with an exit code of `0` indicating success if the s3 object is a directory and it exists. This triggers the

```bash
&& echo "It exists!"
```

If the s3 object does not exist then the exit code is `1` indicating failure. THerefore the `&&` is skipped and instead it triggers:

```bash
|| echo "It doesn't exist!"
```

Or if you want it as a bash script instead then:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if aws s3 ls s3://BUCKET_NAME/PATH/TO/DIRECTORY/ > /dev/null
then
  echo "It exists!"
else
  echo "It doesn't exist!"
fi
```